# R stan returns Variable "rhs" does not exist

Tags: r, bayesian, ode, stan

I am solving an ODE function on, but it returns an error. I am fairly new to Stan and have gone through the manual (version 2.23), I build a variable function and try to use it later in the parameter section.
The error message is below:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
Variable "rhs" does not exist.
 error in 'model3f5c177424bb_pk' at line 30, column 40
  -------------------------------------------------
    28:   vector[N] mu; // Outputted
    29:   { // Local computation - isn't saved or outputted!
    30:     vector[2] solution[N] = ode_rk45(rhs, [D, 0.0]', 0.0, t, ka, ke);
                                               ^
    31:     for(i in 1:N){
  -------------------------------------------------
```

and the stan code is :

```
functions {
  vector rhs(real t, vector y,
  real P,
  real kappa1,
  real kappa2,
  real Pe,
  real Delta,
  real gamma,
  real mu){
vector[3] dydt;
dydt[1] = Pe - Delta *y[1] - kappa1*y[2]*y[1];
dydt[2] = P*kappa2*y[3] - mu*y[2] - kappa1*y[2]*y[1];
dydt[3] = kappa1*y[2]*y[1]-gamma*y[3]-kappa2*y[3];
return dydt;
}
}
data {
  int <lower=0> N;
  vector[N] y;
  real t[N];
  real<lower = 0> p;
  real<lower = 0> kappa1;
  real<lower = 0> kappa2;
  real<lower = 0> Pe;
  real<lower = 0> Delta;
  real<lower = 0> gamma;
  real<lower = 0> mu;
}
parameters {
  real<lower = 0>  sigma;
}
transformed parameters{
  vector[N] mu_C;
{
vector[3] solution[N] = ode_bdf(rhs, [9600*1e-4, 0.1,0],0.0,t,p,kappa1,kappa2,Pe,Delta,gamma,mu);
for (i in 1:N){
mu_C[i] = solution[i,2];
}
}
}
model {
  y ~ normal(0,sigma);
  sigma ~ normal(0,1);}
```

Can someone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry that I am late to this post. I am currently having difficulty with indexing systems of ODEs properly. This example is probably going to solve my issues: https://tbz533.blogspot.com/2019/11/using-constant-stan-functions-for.html

You may want to later check out this nonlinear ODE solving method for Stan, once you get your code issues resolved: https://tbz533.blogspot.com/2020/01/generalized-profiling-with-stan.html

I am editing your code at the moment. I hope this helps, though.

Comment: is this an answer?  It looks like it may be a comment (or a link-only answer?)